# Terminal claims No pyperclip module Found but that I've already installed pyperclip?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm new to learning Python and am trying to execute some Python code from Automate the Boring Stuff (specifically the Password Locker Project). In the book, it tells us to run this program (attached below) through Terminal, so I did the following steps:

1. Saved the code in my home folder and titled it pw.py
2. Changed the .py's files to make it executable by running `chmod +x pw.py`
3. Tried to run my script by entering `./pw.py` on Terminal

However when I run the code, Terminal says there is no module named pyperclip (again, shown below). Naturally, I tried to install pyperclip with the `prompt python3.8 -m pip install pyperclip` but Terminal claims that I've already installed pyperclip. Any ideas for how to solve this problem?

Here is the error I see on Terminal when I try to run my code
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "./pw.py", line 7, in <module> import sys, pyperclip ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'`

> Here is the error I see on Terminal when I try to install pyperclip

`Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.8.0)`

> Here is the code I copied from Automate the Boring Stuff that I typed out on IDLE.

```
PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6', 'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt', 'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
 print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

version: python3

Thanks!

Comment: what python version are you using to run it

Comment: The most recent one which I believe is 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like you have more than one Python installation. You installed pyperclip with `python3.8` specifically, but by executing your script using `./pw.py`, you could be running it with some other installation currently set as your default. Try `python3.8 pw.py` and see if that works.

Edit: Glad that worked! If you'd like to investigate what version your system is using by default, try entering `python --version` on the command line. And as M Z mentioned below in a comment, `sys.version_info` (or also just `sys.version`) can access the current Python version from inside a script.

Comment: When I run that, Terminal reads "Usage: py pw.py [account] - copy account password"

Comment: @coding22314, it had to have successfully imported `pyperclip` to produce that message, so problem solved.  You just need to supply an account name on the command line for the script to actually do anything.

Comment: you can check the runtime version with `sys.version_info`

Comment: Glad it worked. I edited with a little more info if you want to figure out what your system Python is. Please consider upvoting/accepting.

Comment: Hey! I'm a bit confused. So I ran the ```python --version``` prompt and Terminal is saying I'm using 2.7.16. I then ran a ```python3 --version``` prompt and Terminal is saying I'm using 3.8.5. Any ideas which one my Mac is really using?

Comment: @coding22314 Both are installed. 2.7.16 is set as your *default*, so if you just run `python` (or execute a script without specifying an interpreter) that's what you get. When you run python3 or python3.8, you get your 3.8.5 installation. So far, you've only installed pyperclip in 3, not in 2.

Comment: @coding22314, would you consider accepting this answer (clicking the checkmark), please?